# Cannot run python script in a crontab

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to run a python script and I am using this code to run the crontab:

```
SHELL = /home/boogieman/codeCopy.py
PATH = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO = ""
* * * * * /usr/bin/python/ /home/boogieman/codeCopy.py
```

I tried `SHELL = /bin/bash` too but still cannot see any difference.
When I run the `codeCopy.py` in my terminal, it works like a charm. But still cannot figure out what am I doing wrong with the crontab.
Here is a piece of my code which saves a dictionary into a csv file:

```
from time import strftime
t = strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')

body.update({'Time':t})

with open('/home/boogieman/r3edata.csv','a+', newline='') as fhandle:
        writer = csv.writer(fhandle)
        items = body.items()
#       writer.writerow([key for key, value in items])
        writer.writerow([value for key, value in items])
```

I am trying to save a copy of the dictionary every time when it runs.
The solutions I found on several pages didn't work for me. I changed Shell path, updated exact file paths and tried the script accessible for every user.
I explicitly used `/usr/bin/python/` in my crontab command and tried `#!/usr/bin/python/` in my python script too. Both of them didn't work.

Can you please help me fix this? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following line in `/etc/crontab`:

```
* * * * * python3 /home/boogieman/codeCopy.py
```

you can also consider this line:

```
* * * * * cd /home/boogieman && python3 codeCopy.py
```

so you'll be running your script in the correct folder.

Comment: Should I make any changes in shell before attempting this approach?

Comment: No, it works on both laptop and raspberrypi where I use this technique.

Comment: Changing the ```etc/crontab``` worked for me. Thanks a ton